# extracting new models form collections

Tags: backbone.js, collections, coffeescript, marionette

I am trying to develop refresh feature on social feed, Evry minute i am checking if there are some new tweets.

I am fetching a backbone collection (col1) and after 1 min i am fetching the same collection (col2) to compare and extract new tweets.

```
  @tweets = App.request "tweets:entities"
  that = @
  setInterval (->
    that.freshTweetsCol = App.request "tweets:entities"
    App.execute "when:fetched", that.freshTweetsCol, =>
      console.log(that.freshTweetsCol == that.tweets) 
      freshTweets = _(that.freshTweetsCol.models).without(that.tweets.models)
      freshTweets2 =  _.difference(that.freshTweetsCol.toJSON(),that.tweets.toJSON())
      console.log(freshTweets)
      console.log(freshTweets2)
    return
  ), 10000
```

1. @tweets gives me collection with 20 models
2. that.freshTweetsCol gives me collection with the same 20 models as
   in @tweets, if there is no  new tweets.
3. console.log(that.freshTweetsCol == that.tweets) gives false, even if models are the same
4. console.log(freshTweets) gives    me array of 20 models, each called 'Tweet'
5. console.log(freshTweets2) gives me array of 20 objects

how can i check only for new tweets? why I cannot use _.difference method to compare the collections?

Answer (score 1):

*console.log(that.freshTweetsCol == that.tweets) gives false, even if models are the same*
yes this happens [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Use underscore to compare to objects it does recursive comparison

```
_.isEqual(obj1, obj2);
```

**difference** returns array of objects not model's so you should instantiate new Backbone collection like

```
frshTwe =  _.difference(that.freshTweetsCol.toJSON(),that.tweets.toJSON())
var freshTweets = new TweetsCollection(freshTweets2 );
```

or you can reset the collection ([check this](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-reset))

Comment: weird is that console.log(_.isEqual(freshTweetsCol.toJSON(),@tweets.toJSON())) gives true and freshTweets1 =  _.difference(freshTweetsCol,@tweets)   freshTweets = new Backbone.Collection(freshTweets1) gives collection with 20 models